# Can I pass on options from optparse to argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I am wrapping a class that exposes its [`OptionParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.OptionParser) through a property named `options_parser`. I am wrapping this class in a 'runner' that I've written to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse). I use the `ArgumentParser`'s [`parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) method to parse the wrapper's argument, and any of the remaining arguments I pass on to the instance of the wrapped class.

Running `./wrapper.py --help` does not list the options from the wrapped class. Is there a convenient way to add the optparse options to the wrapper's argparse argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's solely for displaying the options, one way I can think of is use the `format_help` of `optparse` and put it in the epilog of `argparse`, for example:

```
In [303]: foo = OptionParser()
In [304]: foo.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",help="read data from FILENAME")    
In [305]: foo.add_option("-v", "--verbose",action="store_true", dest="verbose")    
In [311]: bar = ArgumentParser(epilog = foo.format_help(), formatter_class = RawTextHelpFormatter)
In [312]: bar.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',help='an integer for the accumulator')
In [313]: bar.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',const=sum, default=max,help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
In [314]: bar.print_help()
usage: ipython [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]

positional arguments:
  N           an integer for the accumulator

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --sum       sum the integers (default: find the max)

Usage: ipython [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILENAME, --file=FILENAME
                        read data from FILENAME
  -v, --verbose
```

You can of course format the epilog as you want, including some explanation about the two lists of options. You might also experiment with a different [Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#formatter-class), though the default one doesn't work well in this case because it strips newlines from the epilog. If desperate about the layout you might also try to create your own formatter by subclassing `argparse.HelpFormatter`, though I'd not recommend this based on class docs:

```
"""Formatter for generating usage messages and argument help strings.

Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods
provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.
"""
```